# How do I determine when my Macbook pro was manufactured?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have an early 2011 17" Macbook Pro which is giving me issues related to SATA 6.0gbps; these issues were apparently consistent with the first machines off the line but some of the later machines have been better. I bought my first in March but fed up with the issue I went this week and bought another - alas - same issue.

How can I determine the manufacturing date of the machine?

Answer (score 14):

I'm always hesitant to recommend an app to do what a terminal command could do... but I cannot for the life of me find the terminal command to output the **date of manufacture** of any given Mac.

So...

I recommend the free app [coconutBattery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) for this task.  It's a battery health monitor, and it happens to also show the date of manufacture of the Mac that it's running on.

#### Installation

[`brew cask install coconutbattery`](https://caskroom.github.io) (if you use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)) or download from [the developer's site](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/).

[image: coconutBattery]

Answer (score 5):

This web service can give you information about the date your Mac was manufactured. You just input your serial number. You can find the serial number by going to the Apple menu > About this Mac. The Serial Number is the bottom of the list.

[image: About This Mac Screenshot (OS X El Capitan)]

http://www.chipmunk.nl/klantenservice/applemodel.html

Macrumors.com also has an [interesting article](http://guides.macrumors.com/Serial_Number) about the information encoded in Mac serial numbers.

Comment: As at Jan 2016, chipmunk no longer works, & The Mac serial number is now in 'About this Mac' though in itself will not provide a manufacture date.

Comment: I just tried the Chipmunk service and it still works with my Macs serial. I edited the answer to reflect OS X 10.11. Thanks.

Comment: how does `chipmunk` works?

Comment: Chipmunk does return a manufacturing date for my MBA mid-2013...but it's two weeks off from the manufacturing date returned by CoconutBattery. <g>

Answer (score 3):

https://serial-number-decoder.com/ worked for me.

> It is now one of the most comprehensive sets of serial number decoders on the internet. Aimed at collectors, sellers, dealers and eBayers, it now covers vintage or antique Rolex, Tissot, Timex, Elgin, Casio, Citizen and Omega watches as well as Gibson, Fender and CF Martin guitars, Roland and Boss (which includes all the old analogue gear and Boss pedals), Kawai and Yamaha pianos, DOD and Ibanez guitar pedals, Hot Wheels diecast models and some electronic component dating tools useful for dating vintage guitars, pedals and synthesizers. Recent additions have been tools to **date and identify Apple devices** as well as Samsung Galaxy and Sony Xperia mobile phones.

Answer (score 1):

The serial number of an Apple product has (almost always) the manufacture
date encoded.   For a CPU, first two characters of the serial number is the factory code, next three are the year (one digit only), and week.
So, for my MacBook Pro, the serial number "WQ929xxxxxx"
indicates the twenty-ninth week of 2009 as the date of manufacture.

The format could change, of course, but this has been the pattern for years.

Under the Apple menu, "About This Mac" can be selected, to show the 
serial number, or you can hunt the case of an iPad or iMac for a label.
In case of a repair and motherboard replacement, the software 
might no longer know that serial number.

Answer (score 0):

Try the official [support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1635) page at Apple for determining your MacBook model. Hope this helps.

Comment: @emmby I disagree; the OP wanted the date that it was manufactured, **not the model number.**

Comment: The support page referenced used to give you the date of manufacture.  However, you are correct, it no longer appears to do so.

Answer (score -1):

I've had good luck asking at the genius bar or Apple Care online. They've been able to help me determine manufacture date.

Answer (score -2):

Get the serial number from **About This Mac** menu item and check it [here](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/) . It will give complete information about warranty and manufacturing date.

Comment: The Apple page cited above returns only the generic description (e.g., mid-2013 MacBook Air) and not the date of manufacturing.